# What is the difference between a Sfogliatelle and a Lobster Tail (Pastry)

Tags: italian-cuisine, pastry

What are the differences between Sfogliatelle and a Lobster Tail (Pastry).

There is conflicting information about them being either different or the same pastry.  Additionally, I'm curious of other variants besides the two listed above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference is that in sfogliatelle the filling is made of Ricotta cheese, while in the Lobster Tail the filling is made of French cream.

Lobster Tail is not something prepared in Italy; you find it on New York City. I had to ask to friend of mine living in USA, to know what Lobster Tail pastry is.

Comment: In fact, Lobster Tails originated in Hoboken, NJ, mostly because Italian immigrants in 1910 couldn't source high-quality ricotta.